# Robocopy - How to exclude moving shortcuts and in use files

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I wrote the following batch file `Copy_Desktop.BAT` which should regularly move all files and directories into a specified folder except for shortcuts of programs and and those on which I am currently working on *i.e. currently open*.

```
:loop
robocopy.exe "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop" "C:\Users\Admin\Source" /xd "Folder1" "Folder2" /xf "Copy_Desktop.BAT" /MOVE /S
timeout 300
goto :loop
echo 
pause
```

It does move some shortcuts and it also moves the files I am currently working on but I do not want to have shortcuts of programs be moved and neither shortcuts of programs.

Any idea how to modify my script?

Answer (score 0):

Try using /XF *.lnk to exclude the shortcut files. There's not a specific option to exclude open files. The only way I know to deal with open files is to adjust your /R: value to decrease the number of retries and your /W: value to decrease the amount of time between retries. If you really don't care about any open files then I'd use /R:1 /W:1. This will cause a 1-second delay when you encounter an open file.

Comment: Can you show please how you would modify the script?